# Frequency Response Question on LSI System

Tags: signal-analysis, linear-systems, stability

[image: Still From Edx Signals and Systems]

Someone please explain me the question its seems very complicated to me. I just want know what the question asking and how to solve it i dont want fully solved solution. Thank you!!

Comment: "As proven in lecture ..." Did you take a look at that proof? That's the key to answering this question.

Comment: What is an LSI system? LTI is a common abbreviation that most readers of dsp.SE are familiar with, but LSI was superseded by VLSI a long time ago....